# Simplifying dynamic dictionary creation and looping through it

Tags: python, dictionary

I currently have a dictionary that has capital letters as the keys and a list as the values. The list has a description at [0] and a variable name which points to another dictionary at [1].

```
categories = {'A': ('Song Language', song_language),
              'B': ('Rythm/Genre', rythm_genre),
              'D': ('Atributes', atributes),
              'E': ('Region', region)
              }

song_language = {
    'A1': 'Spanish',
    'A2': 'English',
    'A3': 'Spanglish',
    'A4': 'Non S&E',
}
```

In the case of `categories['A'][1]['A2']` it equals `English`.

Neither of these dictionaries are finalized, meaning I am constantly updating them to add entries. It gets very tedious having to:

- Create additional dictionaries
- Modify existing dictionaries

The use for the dictionaries is to loop through them. First, Loop through the `categories` dictionary and in a nested manner, I loop through the dictionary contained in the [1] of the list.

Each time, I collect input to determine if I am to add the key of the nested dictionary to a list. if user enters 'YL' or 'NL' the script will take some actions and then move on to the next dictionary.

```
for category_key in categories:
    next_dict = categories[category_key][1]
    dict_desc = categories[category_key][0]
    print(dict_desc, ": ", next_dict)
    for attribute in next_dict:
        prompt = "\tIs this song == "+next_dict[attribute]+"("+attribute+"): "
        add_to_list = input(prompt).upper()
        while add_to_list not in ('Y', 'YL', 'NN','NL','N'):
            prompt = "Is this song == " + next_dict[attribute] + "(" + attribute + "): "
            add_to_list = input(prompt).upper()
        if add_to_list == 'Y':
            comment_list.append(attribute)
        elif add_to_list == 'YL':
            comment_list.append(attribute)
            break
        elif add_to_list == 'NN':
            continue
        elif add_to_list == 'NL':
            break
        elif add_to_list == 'N':
            this_prompt = '\t\tDo you want to set any more '+dict_desc+' attributes: '
            any_more = input(this_prompt).upper()
            if any_more == 'Y':
                continue
            elif any_more == 'N':
                break
```

Again, my aim is to move my dictionaries out of my program and finding a more efficient way to creating and managing them since they are always changing.

I still want to maintain the functionality of allowing an user to move on to the next dictionary(category).

For example, if the user is being asked about a language and determines that the only applicable attribute is english they can input 'YL' and that would move them to the 'Rhythm/Genre'  dictionary instead of having to go through the remainder of the `song_language` dictionary.

Comment: You mention that you are looking to move the dictionaries "out of my program". So are you looking for a type of database that allows a user to interact with a front-end and perform the type of search you've made?

Comment: @BillS. While that is a good option, that might be overkill for this and I should of expressed it differently. I would like to either move the dictionaries to a different module or to some sort of file. I think CSV might be the easiest to maintain in the long run.

Comment: Maybe something like https://tinydb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @xdze2!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took @BillS' suggestion and implemented a Database with two tables:

```
    import mysql.connector

    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
      host='127.0.0.1',
      user='something',
      passwd='else',
      database='some_db'
    )

    mycursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)

    mycursor.execute("SELECT main, description FROM categories")
    main_categories = mycursor.fetchall()
    for letter, desc in main_categories:
      .
      .
```